# How do I connect to a new Datasource in Access 2016 VBA?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

My department uses an application created using VBA and Access 2016. It originally pointed to an Access database on one of our servers. After migrating the data to a different server, I now need it pointing to the other SQL Server database on that different server. But I can't seem to make the connection.

I have *dbowner* permissions on the server in question.

The original code for connection string was as follows:

```vb
'Remove the filter, close the log on form, and open the Switchboard
rst.Filter = 0
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmUserLogOn"

'Open the Main Switchboard
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain", acNormal

'Open the InactiveShutDown form in Hidden mode
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInactiveShutDown", acNormal, , , , acHidden
...

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
...

rstLog.Open "tblUserLog", conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
rstLog.AddNew
    rstLog!UserID = rst!UserID
    rstLog!TimeIn = Now()
rstLog.Update
```

My new code is as follows:

```vb
'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInactiveShutDown", acNormal, , , , acHidden
'Commented out the above statement
...    
'Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
'==================================================================
'Start of Added Code for SQL Migration
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
With conn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=(My Server Name);Initial Catalog=(My Database Name);User ID=(Username);Password=(Password)"
    .Open
    If .State = adStateClosed Then
        MsgBox "Connection unsuccessful. Could not open connection.", vbInformation, "Error:"
    End If
End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
With rst
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open "tbl_Users"
End With
'End of Added Code for SQL Migration - See Section 2 for rest of code.
'==================================================================
...

'Section 2 of Code
'==================================================================
'Start of added code for SQL Migration
rstLog.Open "tblUserLog", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
rstLog.AddNew
    rstLog!UserID = rst!UserID
    rstLog!TimeIn = DateTime.Now()
rstLog.Update
MsgBox "Success! Connection was made successfully.", vbInformation
'End of added code for SQL Migration
'===================================================================
```

My form has a drop down to select list of users form a table. I added a test user in that table but that test user doesn't show up in the drop down list. Hence, I think the connection is not being made.

Do I have to enter the names for Data Source, Initial Catalog, User ID and Password in quotes? So `UserID='Admin'; Password='Test'`?

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does you give an error message?  what happens when you try?

Comment: That is not VB.NET code

Comment: also, quotes are correct, but I believe User ID should be uid or UserID (all together).  [Check this out](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/standard-security/)

Comment: No error message. I get a prompt that it connected successfully. It just doesn't show up in the database when I run a search query with those details. I think it still stores the info locally.

Comment: I wonder if the form itself has a connection to the other source then.  You're saying the user you add does not make it to the SQL database you're connected to, but no errors occur?

Comment: Why don't you just `link` the table in Access ? Simple and efficient. You can also use Passthru queries.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have a version confusion of same named table between local Access frontend database and backend SQL Server database. Currently, your code updates the *tblUserLog* on the SQL Server backend side and is not the same *tblUserLog* on the Access frontend side which likely is the one bound to your form. Hence, why you cannot see any update as the server table is never shown.

Simply do one of two things:

1. **Use SQL Server Version**: Delete or archive the Access' version and add *tblUserLog* as an [ODBC linked table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Link-to-or-import-from-an-SQL-Server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e). Be sure to remove the *dbo_* or other schema prefix and keep same name *tblUserLog*. And since table names do not change, everything such as forms and VBA code should not need to change.
2. **Use Access Version**: Keep the local Access table, *tblUserLog*, and update this one in VBA which requires adding another connection object and running a recordset update on that connection. See below with prefixes of *server_* and *local_* on ADO objects:

   ```vb
   ' OPEN SERVER CONNECTION AND SERVER TABLE RECORDSET
   Set server_conn = New ADODB.Connection

   With server_conn
       .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=(My Server Name);Initial Catalog=(My Database Name);User ID=(Username);Password=(Password)"
       .Open
       If .State = adStateClosed Then
           MsgBox "Connection unsuccessful. Could not open connection.", vbInformation, "Error:"
       End If
   End With

   Set server_rst = New ADODB.Recordset
   With server_rst
       .ActiveConnection = conn
       .CursorLocation = adUseClient
       .CursorType = adOpenStatic
       .LockType = adLockOptimistic
       .Open "tbl_Users"
   End With

   ' OPEN LOCAL CONNECTION AND UPDATE LOCAL TABLE RECORDSET
   Set local_conn = CurrentProject.Connection

   Set local_rstLog = New ADODB.Recordset
   local_rstLog.Open "tblUserLog", local_conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
   local_rstLog.AddNew
       local_rstLog!UserID = server_rst!UserID     ' NOTICE SERVER DATA USED HERE
       local_rstLog!TimeIn = DateTime.Now()
   local_rstLog.Update

   ...
   ' RELEASE RESOURCES
   Set server_rst = Nothing: Set local_rstLog = Nothing
   Set server_conn = Nothing: Set local_conn = Nothing
   ```